# Mailchimp use merge tags in link url

Tags: email, url, mailchimp

I am building a mailchimp campaign with a link to a custom form. I would like the fields of the form to be filled in with the info I have from my suscribers (first name, last name, company name, email...)

For this, I am generating custom urls with paramters for the link in the email. Those parameters are then filled in the inputs. The URLs should look like this :

```
http://www.example.com/custom_form.php?
fname=some_name&lname=some_name&company=some_company$email=example@example.com
```

The issue I have is in the mailchimp editor. I want to use merge tags to generate the parameter values according to each suscriber so my link looks like this in the editor :

```
http://www.example.com/custom_form.php?
fname=*|FNAME|*&lname=*|LNAME|*&company=*|COMPANY|*&email=*|EMAIL|*
```

This works fine except when for example the company name is in two words. The URL is broken and the parameters after the company name don't work.

**How can I encode the merge tags for urls?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `*|URL:COMPANY|*`. See the [merge tag cheat sheet](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheatsheet?_ga=1.193870446.2130253608.1417664339#Content-encoding-merge-tags).

Comment: This works, thx for the answer. I had tried this before but I was putting the link straight in the email editor without using the link button. And the merge tags weren't encoded.

Comment: Does this work in the preview area? Can't seem to see the tag rendering properly there.

Comment: No it does not work in the prewiew area.